# When redirecting to another webpage the function keeps repeating

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, event-handling, dom-events

What I want to do is run an animation for 7 seconds then redirect to the actual index.html file, but when I use the code below the animation finishes in 7 seconds it redirects to index.html then it keeps reloading the index.html. I was thinking of using a for loop or if statement but I don't really know where to start.

```
$(function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
      $(".fly-in-text").removeClass("hidden");
   });
   setTimeout(function() {
      $(".allblack").remove();
   }, 7000);
```

---

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     // Handler for .ready() called.
     window.setTimeout(function() {
        location.href = "index.html";
     }, 7000);
  });
});
```

[What my code currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIW8c.png)

Comment: Please **DON'T** post images of code. Check https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/ for more information.

Comment: i suggest to check `location.href` is NOT `index.html` and ONLY THEN load the index. Else you are already in index.html and no need to reload

Comment: I have tried an if statement for it then it would refresh the page every 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

I had to place a meta tag to the page that I wanted to redirect to using

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=index.html" />
```

then I had to add a  JavaScript function script

```
function leave() {
    window.location = "index.html";
  }
  setTimeout("leave()", 5000);
```